# Why does Python's eval(input("Enter input: ")) change input's datatype?

Tags: python, eval, type-conversion

In Python 3, I write a simple command to accept an integer input from the user thus:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

If I skip the `int()` part and simply use `x = input("Enter a number: ")`, my input's datatype is a string, not an integer. I understand that.

However, if I use the following command:

```
x = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
```

the input's datatype is 'int'.

Why does this happen?

Comment: maybe it is a dynamic type check when you use eval()?

Comment: `eval` treats the input like it was written in code, doing `x = 3` in code makes an integer, so `x = eval("3")` will also make x an integer, however letting the user enter arbitrary code as their input can be a huge problem, if they typed in `open(__file__,'w').close()` it would delete the current executing file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

`x = eval(input("Enter a number: "))` is not the same thing as `x = eval('input("Enter a number: ")')`

The former first calls `input(...)`, gets a string, e.g. `'5'` then evaluates it, that's why you get an `int`, in this manner:

```
>>> eval('5') # the str '5' is e.g. the value it gets after calling input(...)
5 # You get an int
```

While the latter (more aligned with what you were expecting), evaluates the expression `'input("Enter a number: ")'`

```
>>> x = eval('input("Enter a number: ")')
Enter a number: 5
>>> x 
'5' # Here you get a str
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a number is a valid expression in Python, and it evaluates to itself (and its type is int). For example, if you input a rubbish string with a non-existing name (say, 'abcdefgh'), a NameError exception will be raised (the exception is raised while evaluating).